# Semaphore implementation using x86 assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, concurrency, operating-system, semaphore

I am interested in the semaphore implemenation scheme, and I learned that in the x86, we could use the "lock prefix" to implement atomic operations, and I want to use it to implement a mutex, I know that C++ 11 has standard mutex now, but I want to implement my own. and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Semaphore
{
private:
    int s;
public:
    Semaphore( int s ) : s(s){}
    void wait()
    {
        int *p = &s;
        _asm
        {
            mov eax, p
            lock dec DWORD PTR [eax]
    begin : mov ebx, DWORD PTR [eax]
            cmp ebx, 0
            jl begin
        };
    }

    void signal()
    {
        int *p = &s;
        _asm
        {
            mov eax, p
            lock inc DWORD PTR [eax]
        };
    }
} s(1);

void print()
{
    s.wait();
    std::cout << "Print Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    s.signal();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv )
{
    std::vector< std::thread > vec;
    int n = 3;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) vec.push_back( std::thread( print ) );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) vec[i].join();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when there is two thread, the code goes well, while in case of 3 threads, the program seems to sink into a deadlock condition, could anyone explain why or give me some suggestions on how to implement is on a x86 machine?

Comment: Like Antti says, you cannot implement any sort of sane semaphore without OS support.

Comment: A proper mutex or semaphore cannot be implemented purely in userspace, since it needs to communicate with the operating system's scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have created is not a proper implementation of a semaphore. A semaphore is supposed to put the waiting task to the waiting queue for the semaphore; after that its code is not run until the semaphore is signalled again; when the semaphore is signalled, a waiting thread is awaken. Half of the semaphore code is in kernel, and details to how to access it is in the threading library implementation. Thus to implement semaphores properly, in C++, you need to do something more complicated. Or you can write your own operating system.

Also, you did not say what compiler you are using, but it is possible that your compiler optimizes the asm clauses too radically.

Answer (score 6):

Your `wait` is really a spinlock -- when the lock is under contention, it will (attempt to) use 100% of the CPU until the other thread(s) release the semaphore. Unfortunately, since it's using 100% of the CPU, that prevents the other threads from getting CPU time, so you get something closely approaching a dead lock.

At a guess, you're probably running on a dual core CPU. In such a case, the other thread can run full-speed, even though the spinlock is sitting in a tight loop, wasting CPU time. When you get more threads than available CPU cores, things drag to a halt.

Spinlocks can be useful if you have good reason to believe the semaphore will be clear quickly (in which case you want to avoid the overhead of a task switch). In a typical case, however, you want to limit the time spent "spinning", so your loop would look something like:

```
        mov ecx, 100
begin : mov ebx, DWORD PTR [eax]
        test ebx, ebx
        loopnz begin
```

Then, after it breaks out of the loop, you check whether the semaphore cleared, or your limit (100 iterations, in this case) was reached. If the limit was reached, you invoke the scheduler to let some other thread run (and re-try the wait when this thread runs again).

Comment: Using "100% of CPU" does not prevent other threads from getting CPU time - no sane OS will let itself be left hanging like that. Any process/thread/task is preempted by a [timer] interrupt, as its time slice runs out for example, letting other tasks have a go. CPU utilization has nothing to do with it, not with preemptive kernels. Please feel free to correct me if you think I am wrong.

Comment: @amn: Okay: You're wrong. Yes, as long as your thread is running at normal priority, it'll (probably) *eventually* get interrupted, and the other thread will manage to run (that's why I said "closely approaching a dead lock" instead of just "a dead lock"). At the same time, he has a thread that's doing its best to use all the CPU, so the other thread won't get a chance to run very quickly--and in a thread with sufficiently high priority, no, nothing else would get to use that core at all (e.g., on Windows, a "time critical" thread can preempt virtually everything else).

Comment: When I say "virtually everything else", I really mean virtually everything--it's given high enough priority that if you run something using all the CPU at that priority long enough, it can crash the machine by preventing memory refresh from happening when needed.

Comment: You did not mention priorities in your answer, and I did not assume. Given equal priorities, thread B will eventually release the semaphore, even if thread A uses "100% CPU", and by eventually I mean in finite time. Am I wrong? That was what I wanted to clear out. If thread A spins waiting for a lock which a lower priority thread B holds, then I do not contest, of course.

Comment: @amn: Yes, usually--but not always. Just for example, on VMS the system didn't do round-robin scheduling among time-critical threads. Once a time critical thread was started, it would continue to run until it finished, even if other time-critical threads were waiting and ready to run.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues at play here.  Here are two.

1. Your wait() routine decrements the counter unconditionally.  If you have two waiters, then your count will be -2 and you will require two signals before any waiter will stop waiting.
2. The semaphore code as written is entirely dependent upon the scheduler.  Therefore, depending upon the scheduler and the priority of the waiters and signalers it is entirely possible that the waiting tasks (which are busy loops) will never yield to another execution context.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I admit that I couldn't implement my own version without the help of the OS or the machine, so I try to using the C++11 standard to implement one, and I found that a course of Stanford gives a solution, and I'd like to share it with anyone who needs it, and here is the link: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs110/lectures/18-threading-and-semaphores.html#(3)